# Are there plans for NuGet to allow commercial library packages to be created?

Tags: nuget

I can't seem to find anywhere on the web that gives a thumbs up or down on this one. Can anyone point me to an answer? Or better yet, if you work on NuGet can you give some indication as to whether or not there are any plans to allow commercial library packages (with some sort of authentication, I would assume) be included in NuGet in a future version?

I love NuGet, but being able to use it for non-commercial libraries in my application only takes away about half of the pain of library management/configuration. I'd love to be able to use NuGet to update my commercial libraries as well!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been discussion with some of the commercial vendors about supporting this sort of thing. NuGet supports adding multiple package feeds, so we may consider adding authentication support so the various vendors could have private authenticated feeds you could subscribe to.

Comment: Just noticed this answer... I hope you guys are still considering adding authentication support. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Authentication support will be in NuGet 1.5! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are already commercial products available via nuget. One example is [mail.dll](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mail.dll).

Comment: I can see how that kind of product would work. The download is free, but you pay separately for a license file. I'm talking about 3rd parties that require you to log in to an account and download a library. For example, I have to log in to Telerik's web site to download and install their tools. I'd love to have some way to simplify that process with NuGet.

Comment: A component marketplace - David Ebbo had some thoughts in this direction ;-) http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/04/new-pricing-model-for-nuget.html